# Splitting page into JS/CSS/HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps

I would like to break this code into one JS, CSS and HTML file each. How could I do that?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  </style>

  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>

  <script>
  var map;
  function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
        mapOptions);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
  </script>

</head>
<body>
  <div id="map-canvas"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Everything between the `<style>` and '</style>' tags (not including the tags) goes into your css file.  Everything between '<script>' and '</script>' go into your js file.  Then replace the style tag with the link to the css file and replace the script tag with a script tag with the source set to the javascript file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can move the Javascript (contents between scripts tags) to a separate file, for example

```
<script src="scripts/myscripts.js"></script>
```

Similarly you can move the CSS (contents between style tags and embed it like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="my.css" />
```

So your Javascript file would look like this:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
 var mapOptions = {
zoom: 8,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
 };
 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
} 

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and your CSS file like this:

```
html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Grax. I broke the codes up as you suggested. My initial error when i broke them up earlier on was that i included the <style> tags in my .css file.